# How do I get pandas to use the value of the column and not it as a series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that comes in localized to different time zones with the timezone in a separate column. I have loaded the data into a pandas dataframe from a postgres database I am trying to combine them so I can adjust as needed. Some metrics on the data will need to be UTC and some will need to be the localized time.

I tried this:

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.tz_localize(tz=pytz.timezone(df['timezone']))
```

And I get AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'upper', I am not sure how to get the row it's working on.

So I did this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     df.loc['index', 'timestamp'] = row['timestamp'].tz_localize(tz=pytz.timezone(row['timezone']))
```

This is working, but takes a very long time to process.

Any ideas on what I am missing or a better way to do this?

Comment: can you show the df

Comment: IIUC, you want each row of column `timestamp` convert to corresponding time-zone from column `timezone`. I.e, each row is converted to different time-zone. In that case, there is no suitable vectorized operation. The best you can do is using list comprehension or `itertuples` to loop each row

Comment: What do you need to see, their is about 50 columns and about 400k rows? timestamp is a dtype: datetime64[ns] and time_zone is a string.

Comment: How about grouping by timezone and using your first attempt on each (with `tz` being each timezone)?

Comment: @AndyL. Thank you, this looks to be better. Changing from iterrows to itertuples. Once I am done testing I will post the answer.

Comment: Please share the entire error message, and a [mcve] (or at least enough data for us to be able to understand the situation). It's difficult to tell where these functions are coming from, which means we might be missing a far better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using itertuples still takes a long time, but is much faster than iterrows. Not much had to change.

```
for row in df.itertuples():
        df.loc[row.Index, 'timestamp'] = row.timestamp.tz_localize(tz=pytz.timezone(row.time_zone))
```

I have not done timeit to know how fast. I will have to look into that later. Thank you @AndyL. for pointing out itertuples.